# Delete file with std::remove with windows username in it

Tags: c++

I deleted a file like this in C++ with `system()`:

```
system("del /s /q C:\\Users\\%username%\\Desktop\\File.txt");
```

I need to know how to remove this with `std::remove`.

I have tried getting windows username and deleting the file with it but I got some errors.

Here is the code that I have tried:

````
#include <Lmcons.h>
  TCHAR name [ UNLEN + 1 ];
  DWORD size = UNLEN + 1;
std::remove("C:\\Users\\" + name + "\\Desktop\\File.txt");```
````

Comment: "*i got some errors*" Such as? We need to see both your errors and a program that can actually be built. Alternatively, it's likely you meant `std::filesystem::remove`, because `std::remove` has nothing to do with files.

Comment: `std::remove` doesn't remove files. [It removes from library containers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Sounds like you're looking for [`std::filesystem::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove)

Comment: You should post the errors.  You have several of them (at least 4).

Comment: yea one second lemme try and thanks guys

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ryuzsv

Comment: I have no idea what is waiting for me at the other end of that link, so there is no way I'm going to click it. Sorry. Add additional information to the question directly. Do not use a link. Even if I trust the link, the suckers rot and take the information with them.

Comment: Let's guess the errors:  1) Adding of pointers to attempt a concatenation, 2) Wrong usage of `std::remove`  3) Missing headers, and possibly 4) Mixing string types (wide and narrow).

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, most of the comments here specify that you use `std::remove`. Guess what, there is another `std::remove` that really does remove a file. It is specified in `cstdio` header.

So the first thing you should do is include this header.
The second thing to do is learn how to concatenate constant/literal strings in C.

In C, "strings" are just plain char arrays. Therefore, you can't directly concatenate them with other "strings".

You can use the `strcat` function, which appends the string pointed to by `src` to the end of the string pointed to by `dest`:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

Here is an [example from cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/):

```
char str[80];
strcpy (str,"these ");
strcat (str,"strings ");
strcat (str,"are ");
strcat (str,"concatenated.")
```

---

As other people suggested, you can move onto https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/remove as it is from the latest stable C++ version.

Comment: i need it in c++

Comment: I posted reference to the function you are looking for.